# Uniform convergence , absolute integral, and a.e. convergence

Tags: measure-theory

I found this on a qualifier exam, and I think it will help me understand convergence better.

$\{f_n\}$ are real-valued integrable functions on $I=[0,1]$, then consider below three statements:

(a). $\{f_n\}$ uniform converges to $0$ on $I$.

(b). $\{f_n\}$ converges to 0 a.e. on $I$.

(c). $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_I |f_n(x)|dx=0$.

Then two of below six conclusions are wrong.

1) (a) $\Rightarrow$ (b).

2) (b) $\Rightarrow$ (c).

3) (c) $\Rightarrow$ (a).

4) (a) $\Leftarrow$ (b).

5) (b) $\Leftarrow$ (c).

6) (c) $\Leftarrow$ (a).

My answer is (2) and (4). Uniform convergence and absolute integral are more strong than 
a.e. convergence.

But I have no deep understanding of the relationship between them.

Answer (score 1):

(2), (3), and (4) are false.

For (2), you take $f_n$ to be a "bump" on $(1/(n+1),1/n)$ and zero everywhere, such that the area of the bump is $1$. Then $f_n\to0$, but $\int_If_n=1$ for all $n$.

For (3), you take  $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1)$, $f_n(1)=0$. Then $\int_If_n=1/(n+1)$, but the convergence of the $f_n$ is not uniform.

For (4), you can take the same functions as for (3). These functions converge everywhere to $0$, but not uniformly.